# Are these holes caused by termites?

Tags: drywall, walls, termite, building

These holes appeared about a week ago. Two holes had been there when I moved in, but I thought nothing of it. I noticed more of them this morning after I removed a painting from the wall.

I have found no wings or droppings.

My house is 15 years old and it had a flood in it some years ago because of something I think in the attic, it's unclear but their was a flood, which ive had people say it's just eating at the wall?????

[image: termites??]

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but are you sure there was a flood due to faulty wiring? Unless, maybe faulty wiring started a fire and you have a fire supression system that flooded the house with water in the process of putting out the fire...

Comment: That doesn't look anything like water damage to me.

Comment: I didn't intend to use the world "faulty wiring" but all I know is that their was just a bad flood that had happened to the house, it was related to the attic, ive only been told this by my grandmother, although I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 1):

Are those in a wall, I think they look like small holes like tacks, or push pins I guess my grand kids even have posters on the ceiling not only walls.

I have seen a lot of termite and carpenter ant damage and it is in wood not Sheetrock or plaster.

I sometimes use the small steel pins that have brass hooks .

OOK has 1 pin to 4 pin hooks in the style I think may have made these holes but I do not think they were made by pests. Or any kind of water damage.

Comment: My home only carried push pins, and i only put two push pins in that wall to hold up my painting, and that was it. I understand what your trying to say, but it's true that termites only go after wood?

Comment: I have had some termite remediation mostly carpenter ants but neither tunneled into plaster or Sheetrock, they did not damage the lath (termites) in a lath and plaster bungalow we bought to renovate but the main beams and the sub siding were riddled with holes (no foundation, beams on rocks or dirt) . The interior walls looked good except the cracks along the 2 walls that we ended up completely removing but I did not notice any holes through the plaster. I have remodeled 4 homes with ant damage 2 severe with entire studs gone and the sheathing holding a wall up no holes through the Sheetrock.